# Ever had any Mantra siddhi and used for real purposes?

Tags: mantras

Ever gained siddhi over a Mantra and used it to fulfill your desires ? Had your wishes came true

Comment: Mantra Siddhi is quite difficult to achieve. People who have done so are already quite advanced in spirituality. Such people are highly unlikely to join and post on websites like this.

Comment: You are not aware of so many things happening in the world.. so what? Stop posting your skeptic nature comments... Spiritual aspirants never publicize their accomplishments.. @Wikash_

Comment: "Spiritual aspirants never publicize their accomplishments" How did you came to this conclusion? @Rickross